# Retry Celery tasks with exponential back off from a node.js worker

Tags: node.js, celery, amqp

In [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) task queue manager [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731435/retry-celery-tasks-with-exponential-back-off) a way to do delayed retries using Python worker.

Is there a way to do it from a node.js worker?

Hint: the node.js worker approach via AMQP is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211848/creating-a-celery-worker-using-node-js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since communication protocol is AMQP there is one module which can utilize the `expiration` AMQP feature - https://github.com/lanetix/node-amqplib-retry

At the time of writing the module was lacking support for about a year.